# Use Qt code from Java with events

Tags: java, c++, qt

I have to use an SDK (precompiled libs) to reach a database which is written in QT and uses signals, when some data is changed, and integrate it into a Java application. 
Ive seen that with QT Jambi its possible to write QT application in java, but how can I include qt/c++ headers, and link qt/c++ libraries?
Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: I guess there are various ways to get there; so I think: this is to broad. Worst case, you would have to write some JNI component yourself ...

Comment: Just google 'wrapping c++ in java', you will find several topics with several different approaches. SWIG (http://www.swig.org) seems to be quite popular tool for it.